# Java Regex: How to Match URL Path?

Tags: java, regex, url

I am trying to extract the first part of the path of a URL.  For example: from `http://foo.com/bar/1/2/3` I want to extract `bar`.  Here is the code I am using:

```
private static String getFirstPartOfPath(String url)
{
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^https?://[^/]+/([^/]+)/*$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);
    if(matcher.find())
    {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
    return null;
}
```

However, this does not match the most trivial url listed above, as in

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    getFirstPartOfPath("http://foo.com/bar/1/2/3");
}
```

prints nothing.  At first glance the pattern string seems clear and like it should obviously work.  What is going wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not matching because your regex is not correct. You have `/*` in the end that is not same as `/.*`.

Use this regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^https?://[^/]+/([^/]+)/.*$");
```

Or remove anchor `$`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^https?://[^/]+/([^/]+)/");
```

Comment: Got it, thanks.  I will accept when SO lets me in 9 min.